# Can not implicitly convert type int to string

Tags: c#, string

When I try to concatenate two characters using the `+` operator, the compiler displays the following error message: "Can not implicitly convert type `int` to `string`."

My code is:

```
const string Expr = ('$' + (char)(39));
```

Why do I get this error? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Well best explained [by Eric](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1516639/570150)

Comment: I don't agree with closing this as "not a real question". Sure, it's not a great question, but it's a real question. It's probably an exact duplicate, so if anybody find a duplicate, closing it for that reason would be fine.

Comment: @CodesInChaos The question already linked by V4Vendetta seems like a good candidate to me.

Comment: Hmm missed that one. Guess we should reopen it, and then close it as exact duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

Using the `+` operator on two chars doesn't concat them. Instead it converts them to `int`, and adds these ints, resulting in an `int`.

A simple solution for your problem is using `"$"`, which is a `string`, instead of `'$'`, which is a `char`, but that's no constant expression, so in your case it'll fail with a new compiler error.

Or you could skip the integer step completely and just use `const string Expr = "$'"`. Or if you really want to use an integral codepoint, you can convert it to hex and use "$\u0027".

In some similar situations a common workaround is concatenating with the empty string `""` first (`"" + a + b`). Or you could manually call `ToString()` on one (or both) of the operands. But in your case turning the `$`-prefix into string is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.but still getting the same problem.

Comment: const string Expr = "$" + (char)(39);

Comment: That one doesn't compile because it's not a constant expression. Just use the `"$'"` alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `String.Concat`:

```
string.Concat('$', (char)39)
```

The + operator on strings is internally translated to that method anyway.

Also, you can't use the `const` keyword with an expression like that. consider using `readonly` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.but still getting the same problem. Its in C#