# Print in Line Center

Tags: c#, char

I am trying to print with alignment. While i know the char code for line center is (27,97,1) ,i am unable to achieve it.In the following code eInit is '\n' while debugging and eCenter is '125' :(. i need to align the line to center . Can anyone help ?

```
        private string PrinterName = "Printer1";
        public string eInit = Convert.ToString((char)10);
        public string eCentre = Convert.ToString((char)(27) + (char)(97) + (char)(1));

        private void bnPrint_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

                PrintHeader();

        }
        public void PrintHeader()
        {

            Print(eInit+eCentre+"Hello"); 
            Print(eInit+eCentre+"Hi");              

        }
         public void Print(string Line)
        {
            SendStringToPrinter(PrinterName, Line );
        }

        public bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
        {
            bool functionReturnValue = false;
            if (PrinterOpen)
            {
                IntPtr pBytes = default(IntPtr);
                Int32 dwCount = default(Int32);
                Int32 dwWritten = 0;

                dwCount = szString.Length;

                pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);

                functionReturnValue = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, ref dwWritten);

                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
            }
            else
            {
                functionReturnValue = false;
            }
            return functionReturnValue;
        }




        OUTPUT:
        125Hello
        125Hi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code was adding character values instead of concatenating characters. I fixed the code by replacing `public string eCentre = Convert.ToString((char)(27) + (char)(97) + (char)(1));` with this:

```
public string eCentre = "";
public string x27 = Convert.ToString((char)27);

public string x97 = Convert.ToString((char)97);
public string x1 = Convert.ToString((char)1);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    eCentre = eClear+x1+x2;
}
```

Comment: More about this here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516572/why-does-c-sharp-not-define-an-addition-operation-for-chars