# How can I get third and fourth letters from string?

Tags: c#, string

I want to get third and fourth letters from PlayerPrefs.GetString("String")
and Parse to int.
for example;

```
string playerLevelstr = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Player")[2] + PlayerPrefs.GetString("Player")[3];
//My Player string is "0012000000" but when I plus third and fourth letter, playerLevelstr should be "12" but it is "96".
int playerLevelint = int.Parse(playerLevelstr);
```

Comment: Why not use `PlayerPrefs.GetString("Player").Substring(2, 2)`?

Comment: Because I did not know.

Comment: Well you do now. :) You should most certainly use that method over your current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code `PlayerPrefs.GetString("Player")[2]` returns a `char`, which is being being converted to `int` (being the ASCII value of the character) when you add it to another `char`.

Do this instead:

```
string playerLevelstr = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Player").Substring(2,2);
```

Answer (score 3):

The indexer on a string returns a `char`.

If you use the + operator on `char`s together, it essentially does integer math on the two `char`s.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516572/why-does-c-sharp-not-define-an-addition-operation-for-chars) for more information on that.

Though that means you should get 99 ('1' is 49, '2' is 50') not 96. But maybe that was a typo on one end or the other?

Regardless, you should either convert the `char`s to `string`s (`.ToString()` on them) or use the `Substring` function on the `string` instead. And don't forget your length/null checks!