# strange char to string conversion behaviour

Tags: c#

In C#, I have this:

```
    public static readonly Char LeftBrkt = (char)171; // <<
    public static readonly Char RghtBrkt = (char)187; // >>
```

and, later on, this:

```
        String fred = "Select";
        fred = LeftBrkt + RghtBrkt + fred + LeftBrkt + RghtBrkt;
```

and, upon completion, fred becomes this:

358Select«»

Now, I can get around it if I use either of:

```
        fred = LeftBrkt + (RghtBrkt + fred) + LeftBrkt + RghtBrkt;
        fred = LeftBrkt + "" + RghtBrkt + fred + LeftBrkt + RghtBrkt;
```

Does this sound like a compile bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1516639/162671) from Eric Lippert.

Answer (score 0):

This is because a character is internally nothing but an integer. Thus the operation `LeftBrkt + RghtBrkt` results in adding 187 to 171. You want to convert the characters to string before:

```
fred = LeftBrkt.ToString() + RghtBrkt.ToString() + fred + LeftBrkt.ToString() + RghtBrkt.ToString();
```

This would also work if you write only this:

```
fred = LeftBrkt.ToString() + RghtBrkt + fred + LeftBrkt + RghtBrkt;
```

Because by the first operand the compiler already knows it should invoke the `ToString`-method on every operand

Best would be however use `String.Format`:

```
fred = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{1}{0}", LeftBrkt, RghtBrkt, fred);
```

Comment: However, the pair before fred become an int yet the pair after behave as I was expecting; it was the inconsistency I was querying

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert from Char to String:

```
fred = LeftBrkt.ToString() + RghtBrkt.ToString() + fred + LeftBrkt.ToString() + RghtBrkt.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not "missing something" so much as not realising that using the `+` operator the compiler attempts to do the right thing - which most of the time is right, but sometimes goes wrong. You need to be more explicit about what you're trying to do (concat strings, not numerically add).

Expressions are evaluated left to right. When you do `char + char` it takes the integer value and adds them numerically. When you do `int + string` it converts the int to its string representation and concatenates them. Thereafter `string + char` also treats the char as a string and concatenates it.

The simplest way to be more explicit about what you want is to use `String.Concat` or `String.Format`

```
var result = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{0}{1}", LeftBrkt, RgtBrkt, fred);
```

or

```
var result = String.Concat(LeftBrkt, RgtBrkt, fred, LeftBrkt, RgtBrkt);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just funny situation. .Net `Char` type is basically `number` and `Character` simultaneously. So

```
 fred = LeftBrkt + RghtBrkt + fred + LeftBrkt + RghtBrkt;
```

Evaluates as

```
 fred = ((((LeftBrkt + RghtBrkt) + fred) + LeftBrkt) + RghtBrkt);
```

That is

```
 fred = ((((Character + Character) + string) + Character) + Character);
```

But `Character + Character` is `int` since we can't combine two `charecters`

And when evaluating `number + string` number automatically converting to string.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the useful and quick responses; I ended up with this:

LeftBrkt and RghtBrkt became:

```
    public static readonly String LeftBrkt = ((char)171).ToString(); // <<
    public static readonly String RghtBrkt = ((char)187).ToString(); // >>
```