# What's the benefit of implicit converting a char to an integer?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, char, implicit-conversion

Just out of curiosity...

I discovered a nasty side-effect working with the Char type, so I wondering why the designers chosen a similar behavior.
The following is valid, because of the implicit conversion:

```
int x = 'A';
```

However, the following is a bit confusing to me, because leads easily to misinterpretations:

```
int y = 'P' + 'Q';
```

Since a string is made up of character, and the "sum" of strings yields another string, why a "sum" of characters should give something different?

Another worse:

```
string s1 = 'H' + "ello"; //yields "Hello"
string s2 = 'H' + 'e' + "llo";  //yields "173llo"
```

All that because the implicit conversion.
I'd like to know what are the benefits of doing so, instead of forcing the user to explicitly "cast" the character to an integer (as the vice-versa requires).

Perhaps my blindness, but I'm seeing more disadvantages over benefits.

By the way, there is already a question related to this topic, but seems that none gave a valid reason, other than "they decided so" or "isn't so bad".

[Implicit Type cast in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503430/implicit-type-cast-in-c-sharp)

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Read again: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1504959/284240 from _"Why is there an implicit conversion from char to int?"_

Comment: Well if you are not satisfied by the [answer from Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1504959/961113), then ....

Comment: It simply was a bad design decision. IMO it should have been an explicit conversion. Overloading `char + int -> char` and `char - char -> int` would solve the common cases for treating `char` as a number nicely without introducing these problems.

Comment: @Tim: I read, and still don't find a valid reason over the misleading expressions I've shown above. Could you show me some example of "great" benefit?

Answer (score 0):

Basicly I see one benefit in here, and I do not belive that it is a bad design decision. Internally characters are integer numbers, either. The conversion between a number and an character, based on equivalence tables is called **encoding**.

However in .NET characters and strings are [unicode encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). The first 128 characters in unicode are equal to the former [ASCII encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

If you want to convert a string into a number (or back) this can be done pretty easy when you assume that characters are also numbers. Imagine something like this:

```
char c = '1';
int i = Convert.ToInt32(c);
```

The offset between numerical characters and numerical representation is allways **0x30**. Internally it is now possible to write something like this:

```
int result = c - 0x30;

if (result < 0 || result > 9)
    throw new InvalidCastException();
```

Note that the example works for characters since 1 character can only hold 1 numerical literal (0 to 9). For strings you also need to multiply the index of the character with 10 and the result and add it to the overall result value.

Of course this is much like it works "under the hood". But for practice it is bad design to use the `operator+` (or minus) for strings or characters. This also has another reason. Imagine the following code:

```
string s1 = "Hello";
string s2 = " ";
string s3 = "World";

string helloWorld = s1 + s2 + s3;
```

When calling the `operator+` the following is happening:

1. Allocate memory for the length of string 1 plus the length of string 2.
2. Copy string one to the front of the newly allocated array.
3. Copy string two to the back of the newly allocated array.
4. Return the new string's instance.

This will happen two times, so you will have a temporary string instance, stressing the garbage collector. Since this example is pretty simple it might not be much, but I also found strings like this many code samples:

```
string sql = "SELECT " + c1 + ", " + c2 + 
    " FROM " + table + 
    " WHERE " + c1 + " = " + condition + ";";
```

Maybe the compiler will optimize this code, but you cannot rely on him. In this case I would prefer a wrapper to `StringBuilder`, or at least `String.Format` that internally uses the `StringBuilder`.

To come to a conclusion: 
Implicit conversion from characters to integers are usefull to simplify encoding, but you should not use plus or minus operators when it come's to build up strings or characters.

Comment: Why is the offset always 0x30? I think this deserves an up vote.

Comment: @stt106: Because it's defined in the ASCII standard (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart)

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Should have thought about that as int 48 (0x30) represents char '0'... By the way, you don't need to call Convert.ToInt32 on a char as c# allows an implicit conversion from char to int.

Answer (score 0):

Try to answer the "why implicit promotion to 32 bit" part: The CPU operates on 32 or 64 bit ints in its registers anyway. This means that the hardware does an implicit promotion. The language tries to not abstract the hardware too much.

That said, it can be annoying.