# Adding int values to char array ASCII value C# & JAVA

Tags: java, c#, arrays, encryption, char

in Java you can easily add an int value to a char array without defining it like this

```
String name = " maisam is my name ";
        char[] arr = name.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            arr[i] += 100;

        }
```

but in c# you need to mention (char) while adding value

```
string name = " maisam is my name ";
        char[] arr = name.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {

            arr[i] += (char) 100;
        }
```

I tried both ways in Java, worked perfectly , no error but in c# it gave me an error, why is that ? I searched everywhere didn't find any explanation regarding it !

Comment: its the syntax of the language

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this piece of code?

Comment: @Avishek I'm creating a basic encryption decryption application, I take a string as input in char array, I add values to its ASCII code, now the value which is being added is the key which will be used when decrypting, I will subtract that amount when decrypting

Comment: @Naz This is not a syntax issue. If you needed to cast the variable you would do it the same way as you would in C#.

Comment: there is no implicit conversion from Int32 to char. Or any implicit conversion to char according to MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more about what's going on behind the scenes rather than a syntax difference. You cast the same way in Java as you do in C#, but you just don't need to in this piece of Java code.
In Java it automatically casts the int to a char type.
But C# works differently, you must cast the value.
It seems as though C# is a bit more strongly typed than Java.

Answer (score 1):

this should work. c# implicitly casts char to int, but not int to char, so you have to cast the added int value to char before assigning to char array..

```
string name = " maisam is my name ";
char[] arr = name.ToCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
    arr[i] = (char)(arr[i] + 100);
}
```

**EDIT:** the code `arr[i] += (char)100;` also works fine. The above code is just an elaboration of the same code.

Comment: that's also working, but this is looking more difficult, if i get to choose an option, from that code to this code, how will this benefit me ? its doing the same thing but code looks complicated

Comment: @ramb0 your c# code runs fine. what error are you getting?

Comment: NO ERROR, what I'm saying is that you have to define arr[i] += (char) 100; in c# but in Java (char) isn't required, I was just asking a simple reason for this :)

Comment: @ramb0 okay, got your point. take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1503478/1682415 you may get your answer

Comment: @ramb0 also take a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/01/why-does-char-convert-implicitly-to-ushort-but-not-vice-versa.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In simple words, there is no implicit conversion from `int` to `char` in `C#`

What you will have for `C#` `int` are,

```
int -> long , float, double, or decimal
```

See the other availability from this [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Since you don't have an implicit conversion like

```
char c = 100 ;
```

But should use Explicit conversion

```
char c = (char) 100 ;
```

Also here it is : `C# char` ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx))

**Conversions**

> A char can be implicitly converted to ushort, int, uint, long, ulong,
>   float, double, or decimal. However, there are no implicit conversions
>   from other types to the char type.