# C# CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'string'

Tags: c#, string, char, implicit-conversion

Could someone explain why I cannot assign char to a string without explicit conversion? Something like this:

```
char c = 'a';
string s;
s = c;
```

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'string'

I know how convert char to string, my question is why compiler cannot perform this operation implicitly.

Is it because of char is value type and string reference or there is something more?

ANSWER:
Colleagues, thanks all for your help, after some research I've found really clear answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52280210/12518860

Comment: Because they are different types actually, look at [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: > Is it because of char is value type and string reference or there is something more?

Simply because of **They are difference type**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I know how convert chat to string, my question is why compiler cannot perform this operation implicitly.*

because there is no `implicit operator string` defined in the `char` type.

I've modified the [sample from msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) using `class` instead of `struct` and it works with reference type too

Btw string is the reference type and char is the struct.

```
public class Digit
{
    private readonly byte digit;

    public Digit(byte digit)
    {
        if (digit > 9)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(digit), "Digit cannot be greater than nine.");
        }
        this.digit = digit;
    }

    public static implicit operator byte(Digit d) => d.digit;
    public static explicit operator Digit(byte b) => new Digit(b);

    public override string ToString() => $"{digit}";
}
```

and then you can convert `Digit` instance to `byte` directly:

```
var d = new Digit(7);

byte number = d; // here is Digit converted to the byte
Console.WriteLine(number);  // output: 7
Digit digit = (Digit)number;
Console.WriteLine(digit);  // output: 7
```

PS [here are the implicit conversion list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char#conversions) for the char

Answer (score 1):

Per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8)

> A string is a sequential collection of characters that is used to
>   represent text. A `String` object is a sequential collection of
>   `System.Char` objects that represent a string; a `System.Char` object
>   corresponds to a UTF-16 code unit. The value of the String object is
>   the content  of the sequential collection of `System.Char` objects,
>   and that value is immutable  (that is, it is read-only).

There is no cast between `char` and `string` type. The possible ways to instantiate a string is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8#instantiate-a-string-object). `string` is a sequence of `char` elements, you can't directly assign simple item to sequence instance, you should use `string` ctor or call `ToString()` method

```cs
char c = 'a';
string s;
s = new string(c, 1)
```

There is also no implicit conversion between `char` and `string` type, as you can see at C# [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#implicit-conversions)

Comment: @Aleksandr Beliavski There is no implicit conversion between these types, as you can see in attached link. I've update an answer

Comment: Yea, I see char struct doesn't have implicit conversion operator to perform conversion to string, but I still do not understand what is the reason of that? As it is mentioned in msdn: A String object is a sequential collection of System.Char objects. So it seems there are no reasons that char struct couldn't have implicit conversion to string.

Comment: @AleksandrBeliavski I'd imagine that its to avoid potential issues.  Assigning a `char` to a `string` might mean that you want a one character string created, or it might be a typo/bug.  So it's better to be explicit to avoid potential issues

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert char to string

```
char c = 'a';
string s = c.ToString();
```

Or:

```
string s = $"{c}";
```

They are difference type and that char is a value type and string is a reference type, so that's why you can't easily turn a char into a string in C#

Comment: That's not a cast.  And the question wasn't how to convert a `char` to a `string` it's why it cannot be done implicitly.