# Write a Basic Car rental program on java / problems

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, summary, sentinel

So I'm super confused and just looking for help :L. This is what the instructions from my instructor were.

Instructions : 
Use a sentinel value loop.

Ask each user for:

- Type of vehicle (May use something other than strings, such as: 1
  for economy, 2 for sedan, etc.)
- Days rented

Calculate the (For each customer):

- Rental cost,
- Taxes,
- Total Due.

There are three different rental options with seprate rates: Economy @ 31.76, sedan @ 40.32, SUV @ 47.56. [Note: only whole day units to be considered (no hourly rates)].

Sales tax is = to 6% on the TOTAL.

Create summary data with:

- Number of customers
- Total money collected.

Also, Include IPO, algorithm, and desk check values (design documents).

{WHAT I HAVE GOING AND MY QUESTION}

```
package yipe;

public class Umm {

    import java.util.*;

    int count = 0;
    static int CarType, days;
    static double DailyFee, Total;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("What vehical would you like to rent?\n");
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for an economy car\n");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 for a sedan car\n");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 for an SUV");
        CarType = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (CarType == '1')
              DailyFee=(int)31.76;
            else if(CarType == '2')
              DailyFee=(int)40.32;
            else if(CarType == '3')
              DailyFee=(int)43.50;

        System.out.print("Please enter the number of days rented. (Example; 3) : ");
        days = keyboard.nextInt();

        Total = (DailyFee * days * 6/100);

        System.out.printf("The total amount due is $" + Total);

    }


}
```

1. How can I fix my IF statement(s) to get proper math results?
2. how would I make it loop for to put in multiple information??
3. how to make summary data?
4. how can I round the Total to only two decimals?

Comment: == 1, == 2. Not == '1'.

Comment: CarType is an int and you are trying to compare it to chars '1' etc... remove the 's

Comment: Thank you a lot I appreciate the help a lot, I did this but still, my math formula still seems to be off when trying to calculate the rate times (*) the days rented Plus (+) that 6%.

Comment: Please don't edit out the questions once they're answered so that this makes sense to future readers who have a similar problem.

Comment: @EJoshuaS but it isn't fully answered. was trying to allow clarity to the next two questions?

Comment: It's still better to leave it intact - part of the point of Stack Overflow is for questions and answers to be available to be searched for by other people with similar problems so that they can be helped by the information too.

Comment: @EJoshuaS sounds good thanks. Sorry, I'm kinda new this is the first question on here.

Comment: @EJoshuaS hey, also can i ask you so ive been stressing that im not doing what my instructer would want concerning the whole "Use a sentinel value loop" from what ive built so far am i following this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `'1'` is actually the *character* `1`, **not** the integer `1`. They're actually very different.

In Java (as well as C#), `int` and `char` types are convertible to each other.

To illustrate, the following actually prints 49:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.print((int)'1');
  }
}
```

Similarly, the following prints `true`:

```
System.out.println('1' == 49);
```

As you can see, the character is implicitly being converted to an equivalent `int` value.

To understand why `'1'` is equal to 49 in particular, look at how characters are represented. In particular, look at the [ASCII chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (which is a common convention for character encoding) - it turns out that the character `'1'` is ASCII 49. Indeed, we can do the same thing we did above "in reverse" to "convert" ASCII 49 to its equivalent character, and the following line prints `1`:

```
System.out.println((char)49);
```

To understand how this kind of conversion works, you may want to read [this rather excellent article linked to in the comments](http://www.atnyla.com/tutorial/data-type-conversion-or-casting-in-java/0/30). If you're curious about how this works in C#, you may also want to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503430/implicit-type-cast-in-c-sharp).

One more point: when you do `DailyFee=(int)31.76`, converting this to an `int` will actually "drop" everything after the decimal point, so this is no different than writing `DailyFee = 31`. This is because 31 is an integer whereas 31.76 is *not* (it's a rational number).

One minor stylistic point: you might consider using a `switch` statement here.

Comment: Re "_In Java [...], `int` and `char` types are convertible to each other._" I think one has to mention the important difference between [_widening_ and _narrowing_ conversion](http://www.atnyla.com/tutorial/data-type-conversion-or-casting-in-java/0/30):

Answer (score 0):

```
package demo;

import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Carrentals {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Double a,b,c,d,e ;
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of days for rent");
a=sc.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Select the type of vehicle");
c=1000*a;
d=1500*a;
e=2000*a;
System.out.println("Press 1 for SUV");
System.out.println("Press 2 for SEDEN");
System.out.println("Press 3 for ECONOMICAL");
b=sc.nextDouble();
if(b == 1)
    System.out.println("The rent is "+c);
else if(b == 2)
    System.out.println("The rent is "+d);
else if(b == 3)
    System.out.println("The rent is "+e);
sc.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package demo;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class carrent {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("SELECT THE TYPE OF VEHICLE");
System.out.println("PRESS 1 FOR SUV");
System.out.println("PRESS 2 FOR SEDAN");
System.out.println("PRESS 3 FOR ECONOMICAL");
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
char z=sc.next().charAt(0);
switch(z) {
case'1':
System.out.println("YOU HAVE SELECTED SUV");    
Scanner suv=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("ENTER THE NUMBER OF DAYS");
int a=suv.nextInt();
int rent1=1000*a;
int rent2=750*a;
System.out.println("SELECT THE CLASS OF VEHICLE");
System.out.println("PRESS 1 FOR AC");
System.out.println("PRESS 2 FOR NON AC");
int b=suv.nextInt();
if(b==1)
    System.out.println("THE RENT FOR " +a+ " DAYS FOR SUV AC IS " +rent1+ " 
    Rupees");
else if(b==2)
    System.out.println("THE RENT FOR " +a+ " DAYS FOR SUV NON AC IS " 
    +rent2+ " Rupees");
break;
case'2':
System.out.println("YOU HAVE SELECTED SEDAN");  
Scanner SEDAN=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("ENTER THE NUMBER OF DAYS");
int a1=SEDAN.nextInt();
int rent1S=1500*a1;
int rent2S=12000*a1;
System.out.println("SELECT THE CLASS OF VEHICLE");
System.out.println("PRESS 1 FOR AC");
System.out.println("PRESS 2 FOR NON AC");
int b1=SEDAN.nextInt();
if(b1==1)
    System.out.println("THE RENT FOR " +a1+ " DAYS FOR SEDAN AC IS " 
    +rent1S+ " Rupees");
   else if(b1==2)
    System.out.println("THE RENT FOR " +a1+ " DAYS FOR SEDAN NON AC IS " 
    +rent2S+ " Rupees");
   break;
  case'3':
System.out.println("YOU HAVE SELECTED ECONOMICAL"); 
Scanner ECONOMICAL=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("ENTER THE NUMBER OF DAYS");
int a2=ECONOMICAL.nextInt();
int rent1E=2000*a2;
int rent2E=1700*a2;
System.out.println("SELECT THE CLASS OF VEHICLE");
System.out.println("PRESS 1 FOR AC");
System.out.println("PRESS 2 FOR NON AC");
int b2=ECONOMICAL.nextInt();
if(b2==1)
    System.out.println("THE RENT FOR " +a2+ " DAYS FOR SUV AC IS " +rent1E+ 
 " Rupees");
else if(b2==2)
    System.out.println("THE RENT FOR " +a2+ " DAYS FOR SUV NON AC IS " 
   +rent2E+ " Rupees");
break;
 default:
System.out.println("ERROR!!!");
System.out.println("PLEASE SELECT BASED ON  ABOVE GIVEN INSTRUCTIONS");
 }
 sc.close();
```

}
}

Comment: Mainly the help should be focused on 1 question (small piece of code) and not do all the tasks for OP (help is fine but not writing service)