# How to choose either char 'A' or 'B' by using random() in C#

Tags: c#, random

I'm creating a board game that a computer can choose either 'A' or 'B'.
I used Random() as below. However, the 'tempChar' shows numeric numbers like '86' and '79' which aren't what I expected.

I'd like to know what I need to change to make a computer select only 'A' or 'B'.

```
public class ComputerPlayer: Player
{
    Random rndm = new Random();
    public new char inputSymbol()
    {
        char tempChar = (char)rndm.Next('A', 'B');
        return tempChar;
        
    }

}
```

Comment: there are lots of examples of 'rolling a dice' out there.....

Comment: `return 'A' + rndm.Next(0, 2);`

Answer (score 6):

[`char` is implicitly convertible to an `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503430/implicit-type-cast-of-char-to-int-in-c-sharp), that's what happens here.

You could use this approach:

```
private static readonly Random rndm = new Random();
private static readonly char[] inputOptions = { 'A', 'B' };

public new char inputSymbol()
{
    return inputOptions[rndm.Next(0, inputOptions.Length)];
}
```

By the way, you can omit the first parameter in [`Random.Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-6.0#system-random-next(system-int32)) if it's 0:

```
return inputOptions[rndm.Next(inputOptions.Length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Next method had parameters as next(int,int) so it treats "A" and "B" as ascii values.
For this what you can do is get random from 2 int values and use if else statement to get "A" or "B".

```
if(1 == rndm.next(1,3))
    return "A"
else
    return "B"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ComputerPlayer: Player
{
    Random rndm = new Random();

    public new char inputSymbol()
    {
        char[] tempChar = { 'A', 'B' };

        var rndmNumber = rndm.Next(0, 2);

        return tempChar[rndmNumber};        
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the Low Quality Queue. Code only answers are not considered good answers, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are less useful to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers.